# KeyError: 'pdf' showing now; code was working previously - why?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.gyp", line 37, in <module>
    for x in url_list["pdf"]:
KeyError: 'pdf'
```

When previously code was working fine.  Aside from shifting what directory the actual .gyp file was in temporarily, I did not alter code.  Any clues as to why this has suddenly become an issue?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import glob
import pdfx
import wget
import urllib.parse
import requests

## Accessing and Creating Six Digit File Code
pdf_dir = "./"
pdf_files = glob.glob("%s/*.pdf" % pdf_dir)

for file in pdf_files:
    ## Identify File Name and Limit to Digits
    filename = os.path.basename(file)
    newname = filename[0:6]
    
    ## Run PDFX to identify and download links
    pdf = pdfx.PDFx(filename)
    url_list = pdf.get_references_as_dict()
    attachment_counter = (1)

    for x in url_list["url"]:
        if x[0:4] == "http":
            parsed_url = urllib.parse.quote(x)
            extension = os.path.splitext(x)[1]
            r = requests.get(x)
            with open('temporary', 'wb') as f:
                f.write(r.content)

            ##Concatenate File Name Once Downloaded
            os.rename('./temporary', str(newname) + '_attach' + str(attachment_counter) + str(extension))
            
            ##Increase Attachment Count
            attachment_counter += 1
    
    for x in url_list["pdf"]:
        if x[0:4] == "http":
            parsed_url = urllib.parse.quote(x)
            extension = os.path.splitext(x)[1]
            r = requests.get(x)
            with open('temporary', 'wb') as f:
                f.write(r.content)

            ##Concatenate File Name Once Downloaded
            os.rename('./temporary', str(newname) + '_attach' + str(attachment_counter) + str(extension))
            
            ##Increase Attachment Count
            attachment_counter += 1
```

Here is one little snippet from when I had it print out my overall url_list, and you can see that it IS adding items to the dictionary (edited here for privacy) flagged as 'pdf' - so I'm truly at a loss as to why it eventually gives me the error.

```
'pdf': ['URLSHOWSHERE.pdf']}
```

Comment: in your url_list check if 'pdf' present or not

Comment: please show the url_list glimpse

Comment: Could this be being caused by PDFs that actually have no attachments, so it isn't creating the needed dictionary entry?  Is there a way I can just move to the next pdf in that folder if there are no attachments at all?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error due to the fact that your dictionary **url_list** doesn't have any key named 'pdf'. Please check your dictionary atleast by explicitly printing it to get a glimpse of its content.

Comment: This seems to be the case, as the first and only thing that prints from that before erring is an email address instead of any file.  But I'm still baffled as to why it has stopped working when it previously worked during tests.       It appears that just the final chunk of code, looking specifically for any file that is a PDF attached within the overall directory of PDFs, is causing errors.  But I'm not sure how to address that.